# How to avoid "unconstrained generic constant" with dependent associated constants in traits?

Tags: arrays, rust, constants

I am in the process of writing a trait with two associated constants: the first is a `usize`, and the other is an array of `usize` where with a length equal to the first constant. Essentially, my trait is equivalent to the following:

```rust
#![feature(const_trait_impl)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

trait Foo {
    const SIZE: usize;
    const ARR: [usize; Self::SIZE];
}

struct S;

impl const Foo for S {
    const SIZE: usize = 2;
    const ARR: [usize; Self::SIZE] = [1, 2];
}

fn main() {
    const TEST: &[usize; 2] = &S::ARR;
    println!("{:?}", TEST);
}
```

As of the current nightly build, this trait definition produces the following error:

```
error: unconstrained generic constant
 --> src\main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     const ARR: [usize; Self::SIZE];
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: try adding a `where` bound using this expression: `where [(); Self::SIZE]:`
```

Unfortunately, the suggested fix is not useful because any `where` bound involving `Self::SIZE` would be infinitely recursive. I was ready to give up until I discovered an alternative that seems to work:

```rust
#![feature(const_trait_impl)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

trait Bar {
    const SIZE: usize;
    fn arr() -> [usize; Self::SIZE];
}

struct S;

impl const Bar for S {
    const SIZE: usize = 2;

    fn arr() -> [usize; Self::SIZE] {
        [1,2]
    }
}

fn main() {
    const TEST: &[usize; 2] = &S::arr();
    println!("{:?}", TEST);
}
```

I am rather perplexed by this discrepancy, all things considered. Is there any way around it, or is it mostly just a matter of waiting for `const` language support to improve?

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows

```rust
trait Foo<const N : usize>{
    const ARR : [usize; N];
}

struct S;

impl Foo<2> for S{
    const ARR : [usize; 2] = [1, 2];
}

impl Foo<3> for S{
    const ARR : [usize; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
}

fn main(){
    const TEST : &[usize; 2] = &S::ARR;
    println!("{:?}", TEST);  // [1, 2]

    const TEST2 : &[usize; 3] = &S::ARR;
    println!("{:?}", TEST2);  // [1, 2, 3]
}
```